# Replicate oh-my-zsh directory tab completion selection with arrow keys

Tags: zsh

With `oh-my-zsh` they've extended `cd` tab completion so that, once the directory selection is active, you can move around all the available directories with the arrow keys, rather than just tabbing through them.

Through searching around I'm unable to figure out how it's done. If it's a plugin that does it then that's fine as I can install `oh-my-zsh` plugins with `zplug`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean exactly, but is it this menu? `autoload -Uz compinit`, `compinit`, `zstyle ':completion:*' menu select`

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I meant thank you!!

Comment: Great! I've created an answer for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To enable the tab-completion menu in zsh, put the following in `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
```

Comment: I got `zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]? ` what's this?

Comment: @Niing I'm not too sure. I'd recommend opening a new question asking about that.

Comment: I think it needs to be `menu-select` and not `menu select`

Comment: To fix the problem that @Niing is having, you should call `compinit -C`

Comment: @kapad I'm not sure. `menu select` worked fine for me. There might be multiple ways of doing it.

Comment: To fix the 'insecure directories' problem, run this once: `compaudit | xargs chmod g-w`